# How can I change an attribute if its sibling inherits another class dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a range of attributes, and any value can be selected. On load, the html would appear as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
</div>
```

If a user selected one of these values, a new class would be added, which would have its own unique css properties. Let's say we select the third value:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="start-range value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
</div>
```

If I were to select a value past `.start-range`, it would be assigned `.end-range`. Any values in between be be assigned `.middle-range` (if applicable). From our previous example, let's say we select the seventh value:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
    <span class="start-range value"></span>
    <span class="middle-range value"></span>
    <span class="middle-range value"></span>
    <span class="middle-range value"></span>
    <span class="end-range value"></span>
    <span class="value"></span>
</div>
```

Is there any way to change the properties of `.start-range` when `.end-range` appears in the DOM?

I was hoping to get away with a CSS-specific solution, but unfortunately there aren't any previous-sibling selectors.

Here's a jsfiddle that is more specific: https://jsfiddle.net/m4L01p37

Comment: seems like there is no css solution for this, are you okay with javascript solution?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Javascript would be fine, would you happen to know a vanilla solution?

Comment: @RBarnes added two solutions as answers. Maybe not the most elegant codes, but they are both Vanilla JS

Comment: This is fascinating, there's a lot to learn from this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty overdone solution, but works if `start` is before `end`:

```js
const rangeItems = document.querySelectorAll('.value')

rangeItems.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
    if (!document.querySelector('.start-range')) {
      el.target.classList.add('start-range', 'blue')
    } else {
      el.target.classList.add('end-range', 'pink')
      const start = document.querySelector('.blue')
      start.classList.remove('blue')
      start.classList.add('pink')
      const end = document.querySelector('.end-range')
      const values = document.querySelectorAll('.value')
      const startIndex = [].indexOf.call(values, start)
      const endIndex = [].indexOf.call(values, end)
      values.forEach((elm, i) => {
        if (startIndex < i && i < endIndex) {
          elm.classList.add('red')
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.value {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  margin: 2px;
  display: block;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Default on load
</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="value"></span>
</div>
```

The point is that I detached the color from `start-range`, `middle-range` and `end-range`.

### OTHER SOLUTION

Actually, I like it better when the data and the DOM are decoupled. Not much easier solution, but everything is controlled by JS (the data, the template, etc.). This way it's easier to add other functions (like `reset()`, because only the JS array has to be manipulated and rendered again to the DOM):

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')
const btnReset = document.getElementById('reset')

let data = [
  { id: 0, class: [] },
  { id: 1, class: [] },
  { id: 2, class: [] },
  { id: 3, class: [] },
  { id: 4, class: [] },
  { id: 5, class: [] },
  { id: 6, class: [] },
  { id: 7, class: [] },
]

const addEventListeners = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.value').forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
      if (!data.find(item => {
        return item.class.includes('start-range')
      })) {
        const startItem = data.find(item => {
          return item.id === Number(el.target.getAttribute('data-id'))
        })
        startItem.class.push('start-range', 'blue')
        addToDOM(data)
      } else {
        const endItem = data.find(item => {
          return item.id === Number(el.target.getAttribute('data-id'))
        })
        endItem.class.push('end-range', 'pink')
        const startItem = data.find(item => {
          return item.class.includes('start-range')
        })
        startItem.class = startItem.class.filter(e => e !== 'blue')
        startItem.class.push('pink')
        const sorted = [startItem.id, endItem.id].sort()
        const filtered = data.filter(({ id }) => {
          return sorted[0] < id && id < sorted[1]
        })
        filtered.forEach(item => {
          item.class.push('red')
        })
        addToDOM(data)
      }

    })
  })
}

const template = (item) => {
  const classes = item.class.length ? ` ${item.class.join(' ')}` : ''
  return `<span class="value${classes}" data-id="${item.id}"></span>`
}

function addToDOM(data) {
  html = ''
  data.forEach(e => {
    html += template(e)
  })
  container.innerHTML = html
  addEventListeners()
}

addToDOM(data)

const reset = (data) => {
  return data.map(e => {
    return { class: [], id: e.id }
  })
}

btnReset.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  data = reset(data)
  addToDOM(data)
})
```

```css
.value {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  margin: 2px;
  display: block;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Default on load
</h2>
<button id="reset">RESET</button>
<div id="container" class="wrapper"></div>
```